# Download URL images for products from excel sheet to insert them as images in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have an Excel sheet that contains 35,000 URL for products images. 
I'm looking for a way to download images from url's 
after that I can insert them to SQL Server as images.
I have no idea about that I need to help.

Any ideas?

Comment: Very unclear - you want to just insert the URL's, or do you want to go out and actually fetch the image that URL refers to and then store the image inside SQL Server? Along with the URL? Please elaborate

Comment: yes 
I want to go out and actually fetch the image that URL refers to and then store the image inside SQL Server Database .
I want to store the image in a field of type image in sql server DB

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: No problem I still in the beginning I can change the image data type to varbinary (max).
but how can I get images from url's in excelsheet and afet that how I can insert them to sql server ?
is that possible ?

Comment: I probably wouldn't do this inside the Excel sheet - create a standalone little program (command-line or whatever you like) which (1) reads the Excel sheet, and (2) for each URL fetches the image, and (3) inserts that information into the SQL Server table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to do something like this in a standalone program - e.g. a command-line utility or something. I coded this in C# and for whatever reason, the online C#-to-VB.NET converters all barfed up and couldn't convert this - I hope you get the basic idea and you can do this in VB.NET yourself.

First step: get the [ExcelDataReader](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader) to read Excel files.

Then do something like this:

```
// define list of URLs
List<string> imageUrls = new List<string>();

// open Excel file and read in the URLs into a list of strings
string filePath = @"C:\YourUrlDataFile.xlsx";  // adapt to YOUR needs!

// using a "FileStream" and the "ExcelDataReader", read all the URL's
// into a list of strings
using (FileStream stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    using (IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream))
    {
        while (excelReader.Read())
        {
            string url = excelReader.GetString(0);
            imageUrls.Add(url);
        }

        excelReader.Close();
    }
}

// set up the necessary infrastructure for storing into SQL Server
// the query needs to be *ADAPTED* to your own situation - use *YOUR* 
// table and column name!
string query = "INSERT INTO dbo.TestImages(ImageData) VALUES(@Image);";

// get the connection string from config - again: *ADAPT* to your situation!
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["YourDatabase"].ConnectionString;

// use SqlConnection and SqlCommand in using blocks
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
{
    // add parameter to SQL query
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Image", SqlDbType.VarBinary, -1);

    // loop through the URL's - try to fetch the image, 
    // and if successful, insert into SQL Server database
    foreach (string url in imageUrls)
    {
         try
         {
              // get a new "WebClient", and fetch the data from the URL
              WebClient client = new WebClient();
              byte[] imageData = client.DownloadData(url);

              // open connection
              conn.Open();

              // set the parameter to the data fetched from the URL
              cmd.Parameters["@Image"].Value = imageData;

              // execute SQL query - the return value is the number
              // of rows inserted - should be *1* (if successful)
              int inserted = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

              // close connection
              conn.Close();
          }
          catch (Exception exc)
          {
              // Log the exception
          }
     }
}
```

This should do pretty much what you need - of course, there are plenty of additional things you could do - read only a certain number of URL's from the Excel file, add more logging (also for success cases etc.) - but that should be the rough skeleton of this little program

Comment: thank you so much for your help 
I get the basic idea from u . 
I will try to do this .

Comment: @Muradoz: if you feel this answer helped you solve your problem, then please [**accept this answer**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/153998). This will show your appreciation for the people who *spent their own time to help you*.

Comment: Hi Sir I really appreciate your help . 
I tried to do that code in C# and I get this error 
for this code  string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Inventory"].ConnectionString;
NullReferenceException Was unhandheld 
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in WindowsFormsApplication1.exe

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @Muradoz: well - do you **have** an entry `<connectionStrings> <connectionString name="inventory" ..... />` in your `web.config` or `app.config` ??

Comment: Yeah...
 It working I have now binary data in SQLserver database
thanks  @marc_s so much

Comment: I tried to Add id & url for image next to varbinary data but I failed 
Can you help me with this C# code

Comment: @Muradoz: **ask a new question!** That's what SO is all about !